# How to make an edit text visible using an onclick in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, onclicklistener

I am having a problem making an edit text box appear when i click a button I have used to make it visible. I have set the edit text to 
    android:visibility='gone'

and used code in my activity to make it visible with the onclick method. 
I have no compilation errors when I run the app, I only get a runtime error when I click the button in the app.

here is the code.

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_orders,
                container, false);

        final TextView t=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Button b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1); 

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View V) {

                t.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               }

        });
        return rootView;
    }
 }
}
```

Logcat

```
07-11 13:54:49.874: E/AndroidRuntime(1116): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 13:54:49.874: E/AndroidRuntime(1116): Process: com.example.thelodown, PID: 1116
07-11 13:54:49.874: E/AndroidRuntime(1116): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-11 13:54:49.874: E/AndroidRuntime(1116):     at com.example.thelodown.Orders$PlaceholderFragment$1.onClick(Orders.java:69)
07-11 13:54:49.874: E/AndroidRuntime(1116):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
07-11 13:54:49.874: E/AndroidRuntime(1116):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
07-11 13:54:49.874: E/AndroidRuntime(1116):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-11 13:54:49.874: E/AndroidRuntime(1116):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-11 13:54:49.874: E/AndroidRuntime(1116):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-11 13:54:49.874: E/AndroidRuntime(1116):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-11 13:54:49.874: E/AndroidRuntime(1116):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 13:54:49.874: E/AndroidRuntime(1116):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-11 13:54:49.874: E/AndroidRuntime(1116):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-11 13:54:49.874: E/AndroidRuntime(1116):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-11 13:54:49.874: E/AndroidRuntime(1116):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Layout

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TASK " />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="Enter your orders here"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

Comment: what is the runtime error?

Comment: Add the button method as you have it inside de method onActivityCreated

Comment: can you please post the Logcat..

Comment: what is line no 69 in orders.java???

Comment: Are you sure that the `TextView` and the `Button` is in `fragment_orders.xml`???

Comment: yes the views are definitely in the right xml

Comment: you must have not declare the id in xml

Comment: t.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); is line no. 69

Comment: please post your Layout file too..

Comment: what are you doing . in your xml you have EditText and in coding you are getting it using TextView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `TextView` with id `textView1` is found in your Layout..

I think you mistook..

So please convert

```
final TextView t=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

to

```
final EditText t=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```